# Pass view from controller, to view, and back to controller in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have the following in my controller method:

```
@comment = Comment.where(:reviewed_at == nil).first
```

Then, in my view, I have this:

```
<b><%= @comment.comment %></b>
<br>
<br>

<%= simple_form_for :phrase do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :phrase, label: 'Phrase you would like to add:' %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :emotion, collection: [[true, 'Positive'], [false, 'Negative']], as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Emotion', label_method: :last %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :category, collection: @categories, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Categories', label_method: :last %>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Add to Dictionary' %>
<% end %>
```

When that `:submit` button is pushed, I need to also pass `@comment` back to my controller, or access `@comment` from my controller somehow. I tried using-

`f.hidden :comment, :value => @comment`

within my `simple_form_for block`, but no dice. I know I could just look the comment up again by querying the DB, but I feel like that's not the right way to do this. How can I pass my variable to the view and then back to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant transfer an object in a `hidden_field` but you can transfer the id by adding this to your form

```
f.hidden_field :comment_id, :value => @comment.id
```

So in the receiving controller action you can access the comment by the following line

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:phrase][:comment_id])
```

This should do it for you,... Its a better way to query the db then passing an object from one action to another because that can cause terrible problems when you have changes in the database but use an outdated object and save or edit this object and write it back to the db.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.